# Embed Interop Types property is missing in CLR Project

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, c++-cli, clr

I have a `CLR Empty Project` (.NET Framework 4.6.2) I've noticed that the `Embed Interop Types` is not present in the References Properties, I couldn't find a workaround, is there a way to turn it on? It looks like it's only available on C#.

Comment: Embedding is not implemented for the C++/CLI compiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I come up with the following workaround:

Add the particular assembly you want to embed into your project, right click on it, select `Properties` then set `Item Type` to `Compiled Managed Resource` and put the following snippet at the first lines inside the main:

```
[System::STAThread]
int main()
{
    System::AppDomain::CurrentDomain->AssemblyResolve += gcnew System::ResolveEventHandler(&loadEmbeddedAssembly);
}
```

And at somewhere there:

```
System::Reflection::Assembly^ loadEmbeddedAssembly(System::Object^ sender, System::ResolveEventArgs^ args) {

    System::Reflection::AssemblyName^ assemblyName = gcnew System::Reflection::AssemblyName(args->Name);

    System::String^ resourceName = assemblyName->Name + ".dll";

    System::IO::Stream^ stream = System::Reflection::Assembly::GetExecutingAssembly()->GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName);

    array<System::Byte>^ assemblyData = gcnew array<System::Byte>((unsigned long)stream->Length);
    try {
        stream->Read(assemblyData, 0, assemblyData->Length);
    }
    finally {
        if (stream != nullptr) delete stream;
    }

    return System::Reflection::Assembly::Load(assemblyData);
}
```